# Linking a low variable to an entry

Tags: matrix, low-variables

How can we link a low variable to an existing channel entry?

Let's say a matrix low variable needs to be displayed only on a certain channel entry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Low Variables fieldtype, see https://gotolow.com/addons/low-variables/docs/fieldtype

Add a field of the LV type to the channel, so you can select a variable for any given entry in that channel.